# Colorbox functions such as $.colorbox.resize(); and $.colorbox.close(); from within Outside HTML (Ajax) implementation

Tags: resize, colorbox

While building the majority of a site locally, I had this tactic working perfectly. When I moved it to a server to more appropriately link things up, it broke. I've checked my file paths and everything looks good.

I'm trying to open outside HTML (but from within the site). The pages are in series - much like you would put a series of images in series. Clicking next or previous loads the content nicely but with the opportunity of having different amounts of content, I need to resize. This was working locally and not on the server. As well, the custom close button does not close.

```
$("a.colorbox-personnel").colorbox({
    opacity:.75,
    scrolling:false,
    onComplete:function() {
        $("ul.prev-next li a").live("click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#cboxLoadedContent").load($(this).attr("href"), function(){
                $.colorbox.resize();
            });
        });
        $("a.team-popup-close").live("click",function(event){
            $.colorbox.close();
        });
    }    
});
```

I tried calling other colorbox functions such as:

```
$("ul.prev-next li a").live("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#cboxLoadedContent").load($(this).attr("href"), function(){
        $.colorbox.resize();
        **$.fn.colorbox({href: $(this).attr("href")});**
    });
});
```

And it loads another instance of colorbox over the top of mine. So I feel like Colorbox is hooked up properly and just not firing resize or close. All help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to see if you are generating any errors?  What does your JavaScript console say?

My guess is that the snippets of HTML you are loading ($(this).attr("href")) contain a script element pointing to the jQuery library.  This replaces the instance of jQuery that original existed in your document, which also removes colorbox.  This would cause colorbox's methods to fail of course.

Comment: That was it exactly - maybe when I had it working locally I was mis-calling the jQuery library from within those documents. I didn't know I couldn't have those in there - and on second thought- don't know why I did. Thanks so much for getting back to me. I absolutely love your work.